# Error llamada a SOAP con srping boot

Tags: spring-boot, soap

Estoy intentando consumir un servicio SOAP desde spring boot pero me da siempre el mismo error:

```
El mensaje con la acción '' no se puede procesar en el destinatario debido a una falta de coincidencia de ContractFilter en EndpointDispatcher. La razón puede ser que los contratos no coinciden (falta de coincidencia de las acciones entre el remitente y el destinatario) o que el enlace/seguridad no coinciden en el remitente y el destinatario. Compruebe que el remitente y el destinatario tienen el mismo contrato y el mismo enlace (incluidos los requisitos de seguridad, por ejemplo Message, Transport, None).
```

He probado a generar los esqueletos de peticion ocn wsimport y con wsdl2java, ambos plugins de maven y en ambas ocasiones se repite el mismo erro al consumir el SOAP.

Por lo que puede estar investigando creo que puede ser problema del espacio de nombres, pues al hacer la llamada haciendo debug, intenta lanzar al peticion a :
org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent - Sent request [SaajSoapMessage {http://tempuri.org/}ObterTodosPontosEntrega]

Sin embargo si hago la llamada desde el SOAPUI la llamada la hace a:
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IReferenciasWS/ObterTodosPontosEntrega"

La diferencia es ese IReferenciasWS.
Por lo que veo eso esta definido en el interface que se genera en los src/generated/java
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "IReferenciasWS")

Sabe alguien a que puede ser debido?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola, pudiste ver esto? me está pasando exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Logré resolver el problema añadiendo una cabecera de SoapAction. Por defecto spring es no la añade,

Comment: Hola @ManuelDemanuel como añadiste la cabecera? me pasa lo mismo